# php contact form that i've downloaded doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, installation, contacts

I've downloaded a contact form from http://reusableforms.com/category/contact-forms this webpage. But it doesn't work in my page, I think that the problem might be that I haven't got php well installed, but I can't install it.

I hope somebody can help me,

Comment: Try to provide helpful information in your question, like parts of the sourcecode of the form and the name of the file you want it to be in.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and run a small PHP script like this to see if PHP was properly installed ::

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Delete it after verifying PHP works.

Comment: Are you installing on your PC?  If so, there are a few choices out there like WampServer and XAMPP.